# Ajax load click function only works once

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I've been fiddling for a couple hours now and I can't figure out why this is happening.

I've written a jquery navigation script that replaces content in a div called "contentwrapper". The content is supposed to hide, a loading animation is displayed then disappears, and the new content fades in. The problem is that the animation does not happen every other time. On first click, it works, but the page refreshes on the second click. The cycle continues. It's as if the click function is not active despite the use of `.on()`. Here is my code:

```
$(window).ready(function(){

    $('.menu_top').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#loading").show();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    history.pushState({}, '', href);
    $('#contentwrapper').fadeOut('normal').hide().load(href + "#contentwrapper >  *").fadeIn('slow');

return false
});
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    $("#loading").fadeOut();
});
});
```

Here it is [in action](http://www.fueledbykyle.com/sites/mwood/index.html)

I tried applying everything I could find on the interwebs, to no avail.

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but `$(window).ready(fn)` should be `$(document).ready(fn)`.

Comment: I don't see what the issue is on your demo page.  Each menu item at the top loads new content for me on the first click.

Comment: you don't mention any issue, also the so-called demo is not demo, it's some kind of actual site, viewing its code requires some element inspecter tool of the browser.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're right it should be document. As I mentioned, the script only behaves properly half of the time. Each menu item loads content but not with the smooth fade motions from the script every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know why this is happening.

In your click handler, your final statement is:

```
return false
```

Which indicates that you want the click event to be 'cancelled' after running your code (which AJAX-loads the content into the page).

The problem is that it actually fails to prevent the click event to be 'cancelled'. Look at the URL/address bar in your browser: when you click on the header items, you will see that the URL changes. Your browser is reloading the page every time. Sometimes you will get to see the animation because the AJAX request completes before the browser loads the page.

In order to fix this, I suggest you make your header elements something other than anchors (<a>). Make them inline paragraph blocks (<p>) or something. jQuery can detect clicks on any element so your code will work.

Finally, if you do the above, and you still want to support browsers with JavaScript disabled, you could use a <noscript> block which would use the old-school anchors (with href attribute and everything) for those people. This is optional and only if you want support for users without Javascript (small minority).

Comment: I think the URL in the URLbar is changing because of the `.pushState()` line of code, not because the page is being reloaded.  `return false` from a jQuery click handler will do `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` which will avoid the default link handling.

Comment: jfriend is correct again. Without `return false`, the <a> tags would use their default action. Changing them to <p> proved my suspicion: `.load(href + "#contentwrapper >  *")` is loading the entire page into the div #contentwrapper. Is there something wrong with that code?

Comment: FIXED. `return false` served it's purpose until the code become more complicated. Removing it and then changing the links from <a> tags makes the script behave normally 100% of the time. Thanks for the input guys.